# CrashlyticsMissingDependencyException when compiling debug release on Android Studio

Tags: android, crashlytics

I'm receiving this error every time I compile the debug version of my app

```
03-04 12:02:48.241    8933-8933/com.cmr.activities E/Fabric﹕ This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization
```

The problem it self is, I know the meaning of the error but I have all installed and when I had this error in the past I just cleaned the project and worked again. Now suddenly I'm receiving this error and now I can't fix it. Any idea?

I worked with Crashlytics since past year in several projects but I hate this "crash", and is worst with flavors changes configurations.

Actual configuration:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.15.2'
}

....
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

And in Application

```
public void onCreate() {
    ...
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    ...
}
```

And of course, Android Studio plugin installed and logged in.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using flavors?

Comment: yes, but now is working fine. I think was a release version problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this today and I solved it by removing everything crashlytics related in my code and do an "invalidate caches / restart", then select crashlytics and install via the plugin.